# Use regular expressions in Python to search for courses converted from PDF

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a regular expression in Python to search a txt document for strings.  The strings I'm looking for look like:

1. `ACCT 221 Principles of Accounting II (3) Prerequisite: ACCT 220`
2. `ASTD 485 Issues in East Asian Studies (3) (Intended as a final capstone course to be taken in a student's last 15 credits.) Prerequisites: ASTD 284 (or ASTD 150) and 285 (or ASTD 160).`
3. `ASTR 100 Introduction to Astronomy (3) (Not open to students who have taken or are taking any astronomy course numbered 250 or higher. For students not majoring or minoring in a science.) Prerequisite: MATH 012 or higher.`
4. `ASTD 380 American Relations with China and Japan: 1740 to Present (3) (Fulfills the general education requirement in the social sciences.) A study of American political, economic, and cultural relations with China and Japan from the American colonial era to modern times…`

What I want to the expression to find is the string starting with the course code `i.e. ACCT 221` and ending with the sentence that contains the Prerequisites.  In some cases there will not be a prerequisites sentence, as in example 4.

Here's what I have so far:

```
[A-Z]{4} \d{3}(?:(?![A-Z]{4}).){4,100} \(\d\).*?\.(?!\))
```

This works for examples 1 and 2, but not for example 3 (I actually added the `(?!\))` to catch  things in instances like example 2, not realizing that there were instances of multiple sentences, and therefore periods, inside parenthesis).

What I think I'm looking for is a way to search for a string that starts with the expression I've written up to `\(\d\)`and ends with a period that is *NOT* inside parenthesis, wherever those parenthesis might be.  I tried to add `.*` to the negative lookahead at the end, but that didn't work right.  I tried to add `.*?` to make it non-greedy so it wouldn't return the entire file starting with the first course code, but it didn't make a difference.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: How are the strings stored in the text file? Separate lines?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I converted it from pdf, so it's all in there together without sensical line breaks or spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using two regex for a simpler regex overall:

```
import re

text = '''\
ACCT 221 Principles of Accounting II (3) Prerequisite: ACCT 220
ASTD 485 Issues in East Asian Studies (3) (Intended as a final capstone course to be taken in a student's last 15 credits.) Prerequisites: ASTD 284 (or ASTD 150) and 285 (or ASTD 160).
ASTR 100 Introduction to Astronomy (3) (Not open to students who have taken or are taking any astronomy course numbered 250 or higher. For students not majoring or minoring in a science.) Prerequisite: MATH 012 or higher.
ASTD 380 American Relations with China and Japan: 1740 to Present (3) (Fulfills the general education requirement in the social sciences.) A study of American political, economic, and cultural relations with China and Japan from the American colonial era to modern times'''

courses={}
for line in text.splitlines():
    course=re.match(r'([A-Z]{4}\s+\d{3})', line).group(1)
    m=re.search(r'Prerequisites?:\s*(.*)', line)
    if m:
        pre=m.group(1)
    else:
        pre='None'    
    courses[course]=pre

print 'COURSE\t\tPREREQUISITE'    

for course in sorted(courses.keys()):
    print '{}\t{}'.format(course, courses[course])
```

Prints:

```
COURSE      PREREQUISITE
ACCT 221    ACCT 220
ASTD 380    None
ASTD 485    ASTD 284 (or ASTD 150) and 285 (or ASTD 160).
ASTR 100    MATH 012 or higher.
```

Comment: I'm about to go on lunch, so I won't be able to come back for about an hour to comment more.  But so far, I'm getting an error saying that `m` doesn't have attribute `group` because it's Nonetype.  I'm pulling the string from a file, and the courses are not nicely placed on single lines if that makes a difference.  However, the format you've given me, is absolutely beautiful and preferable.

Comment: sorry, it's saying that the line with `course = ` in it does not have the attribute `group`

Comment: ok so after looking into it, it seems that the match is simply not matching anything.  I'm guessing it has to do with the abysmal formatting of the txt file.  I'll look into it some more during lunch.  I'm trying to get a legitimate txt format of the catalog so I don't have to deal with the converted from pdf version.  I have a feeling the legitimate txt format will make your solution work.

Comment: My guess is that the `test.splitlines()` is the culprit on the converted PDF. For this to work, the individual courses (like `ACCT 221`) need to be at the start of a line.  To debug, add `print line` in the loop before the regex and see what it is trying to match.

Comment: yup, it pulls the whole file.  It may be prudent for me to work on my function for converting from pdf to txt to try to get it to give me a better txt file with sensical line breaks.  I'll have to try to figure out pyPdf some more.  Also, unfortunately there isn't a legit txt version :/

Comment: on second thought, since it's pulling the whole file that means it's not finding any line breaks at all… So I'll probably try to fix my function so that it picks up line breaks appropriately from the pdf formatting.  I'll have to look into how pdf signifies line breaks and then how pyPdf reads it.

Comment: Yes -- that is the issue. Your text stream from the PDF may have funky line ending and the first line read is the entire file. Look closely at the contents of the stream. See if you see a single CR or LF or some character that marks the line end that is not being correctly interpreted when you read it.

Comment: just thought of something while looking at my pdf converter method.  I could use regex to find `[A-Z]{4} \d{3} .{4,100} \(\d\)` and then add a line break before those places… what do you think?

Comment: hello.  Thanks again for all your help.  I was able to use your solution, slightly modified `with open('catalog.txt', 'rU') as f:
 filein = f.readlines()
 

 courses={}
 for line in filein:
  check = re.match(r'([A-Z]{4}\s+\d{3})', line)
  if check:
   course=check.group(1)
  else:
   continue
  m=re.search(r'(Prerequisites?.*?\.)', line)
  if m:
      pre=m.group(1)
  else:
      pre='None'    
  courses[course]=pre
` after modifying the way the pdf converter function translated to txt by forcing line breaks before the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible if parenthesis are not nested:

```
[A-Z]{4} \d{3}(?:(?=([^.()]+))\1|\([^)]*\))+\.
```

Comment: that regular expression puts my program in an infinite loop.
`pattern = recompile([regex])`    `with open('catalog.txt', 'rU') as f:
    filein = f.read()
    group = pattern.finall(file in)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for everything from the four letter department through the first period after "Prerequisites," right? So make that explicit.

```
>>IN:
txt = """
ACCT 221 Principles of Accounting II (3) Prerequisite: ACCT 220.
ASTD 485 Issues in East Asian Studies (3) (Intended as a final capstone course to be
taken in a student's last 15 credits.) Prerequisites: ASTD 284 (or ASTD 150) and 285
(or ASTD 160).
ASTR 100 Introduction to Astronomy (3) (Not open to students who have taken or are
taking any astronomy course numbered 250 or higher. For students not majoring or
minoring in a science.) Prerequisite: MATH 012 or higher."""

pat = re.compile([A-Z]{4}.*?Prerequisites?.*?\.)
courses = pat.findall(txt)
for course in courses:
    print(course+"\n")

>>OUT:
ACCT 221 Principles of Accounting II (3) Prerequisite: ACCT 220.

ASTD 485 Issues in East Asian Studies (3) (Intended as a final capstone course to be
taken in a student's last 15 credits.) Prerequisites: ASTD 284 (or ASTD 150) and 285
(or ASTD 160).

ASTR 100 Introduction to Astronomy (3) (Not open to students who have taken or are
taking any astronomy course numbered 250 or higher. For students not majoring or
minoring in a science.) Prerequisite: MATH 012 or higher.
```

Comment: that's an awesome alternative.  Much more sensical than my solution.  I didn't mention that sometimes the Course code and name will not be followed by Prerequisite/s.  How would I account for those occurrences at the same time?

Comment: It kind of shortcircuits my solution. Can I see an example of that? The solution by @CasimiretHippolyte may be better, if that's the case.

Comment: `ASTD 380 American Relations with China and Japan: 1740 to Present (3) (Fulfills the general education requirement in the social sciences.) A study of American political, economic…`

Comment: About to head out of the office. Will try to spend more time on this when I get home. I feel like you should be able to manage this in some sort of holistic approach by splitting across course numbers if not preceded by Prerequisite or Prerequisites. No time to investigate now.

Comment: If I use your solution as is, it ends up pulling some of the longer strings in the txt file.  I really should think of some way to get rid of most of the txt garbage at the beginning of the file.  The textile is actually an entire pdf school catalog converted to txt.  I'm trying to edit your solution to make it work using `|`